# Make the content take all the left space exclude the header and footer with fixed size

Tags: html, css

I have a html page which contains there sections `header`, `content` and `footer`.

The `header` and `footer` have a fixed height, then I want the `content` take the rest height, this is what I have tried, but it seems that it does not work in IE:http://jsfiddle.net/g1yk9fs1/

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: are both the header and footer always fixed and visible on screen? or only if the content is shorter than the height of the window are you trying to push the footer to the bottom like this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ ?

Comment: No, the header and footer are always fixed and visible on the screen.

Comment: so fixing the header and footer and having the page scroll the content like this? http://jsfiddle.net/g1yk9fs1/6/

Comment: In fact, I do not need the scroll bar at all, the `content` just take the rest space.

Comment: then you can add something like `overflow:hidden;` onto the content container which should remove the scrollbars.